# Changing port on ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Anybody know if I can setup ssh to communicate on more than one port, or change the default port to something else.

Is there a config file I can use to do this on Linux?

Comment: Why is it so hard to read the man pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by editing the sshd_config file. You can take a look at this tutorial for more info:
http://iserialized.com/changing-default-ssh-port-on-ubuntu/

A well explained tutorial.